# WP API to fetch all the media/posts records if count is more than 100

Tags: wp-query, wp-api

I am using per_page instead of the filter since it is no more available. but the problem is per_page value can be between 1 and 100. what if I want to pull records and it is more that 100. per_page will not return records if the count is more than 100.
in the below API I want to pull the images which are more than 100 in count.

http://domain_name/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?per_page=100

Appreciate your help

Srikant

Comment: A little late to the party but you can find the answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/281881/125601

Answer (score 1):

Add a page number query to your request URL, and continue querying next page numbers until you get an empty result:

```
<your_wordpress_install_base_url>/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?per_page=100&page=2
```

Mark's suggestion to consider requesting less than 100 per page may be a good one. So for example you may want to do your query this way:

```
<your_wordpress_install_base_url>/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?per_page=25&page=3
```

Note also that (for me at least) these query URLs work if constructed as just ~/`media?per_page=3` (instead of ~/`media/?per_page=3`). I don't know whether one or the other is preferred.

Thanks, incidentally, for the `/media/?per_page=100` part of your example. I'd been stumped about getting empty results when querying just `/media` :)

Comment: This is a hack and by no means a valid way of approaching things. That's neither efficient nor useful. Why would you do that ? You will end up multiplying queries to your server for what ? It's much better to make your own call where you limit and define exactly what you need rather than hack things that are not meant to be used that way.

Comment: See my comment to your (abrasive) criticism to my reply in your answer.

Comment: Also, it is a valid way of approaching things. It in fact works.

Answer (score -1):

You can [add a route](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) to your wordpress REST api. Make it so you can extract as many images as you need. You can copy the current route for getting the images and delete the maximum filter so you do not run into this issue.

Comment: There is no need to add a route here. This can be done with a method of the existing API (posting an answer...)

Comment: Absolutely not. You do not use loops on a query to construct a new query. I'm happy to take in constructive criticism and find better solutions but hacking your way out is not the correct approach.

Comment: Actually, I *did* use loops on a query to construct a new query, so you (I) *do* do that--did that! ;) In fact, I absolutely did! :) My answer also works with the existing API limitations.

I offered a specific solution; your answer did not. You link to an (outdated) article (updating the URL with an edit) that generally explains how to add routes; but you don't offer a specific example of doing so for this case.

Also, Mark's comment in his answer about generating a lot of results being potentially slow is valid. My "hack" can break that up into smaller queries that could fail gracefully.

Comment: The OP asked a specific question. You answer a different one. assuming the the OP is not smart enough to figure out by himself how to send multiple requests is not a reason to feel smug about yourself. Anyway the idea is to downvote wrong answers, not answers that are not good enough in your opinion

Answer (score -1):

Create new php file with following content and use it as a new endpoint:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', 'Content-Type: application/json'); // Avoid cross origin block

$url1 = 'https://www.example.com/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=1'; // path to your JSON file
$url2 = 'https://www.example.com/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=2'; // path to your JSON file
$json1 = file_get_contents($url1);
$json2 = file_get_contents($url2);

$my_array1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$my_array2 = json_decode($json2, true);
$res = array_merge($my_array1, $my_array2);
$json_merge = json_encode($res);

echo $json_merge; // new json
```

And use it as a new endpoint. This is an example for 200 posts, you can add more input endpoints as you want.

Answer (score -2):

Limits are there for a reason, before trying to overcome them you should ask yourself, "why is there a limit". The limit is there because if the response is unbounded everybody would be able to simply DOS any site by crashing the webserver or DB by asking to get all posts in one request.

Even without that consideration getting even 100 is likely to be slowish. If you want to use the REST API, just get the data in small amounts only when it is actually needed.

Still want to get more than 100? Write your own json end point and handler.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of a need to get all media (by whatever means, optimal or not). Posting my answer . . .

Comment: and there is zero difference between your answer and mine, but whatever

Comment: My answer provides an example of an actual query, or in other words, it specifically answers the question ;) while your answer does not. I downvoted your answer for that reason. Your best approximation of an answer is "just get the data in small amounts," which doesn't tell the OP how to do anything.