# Increase per_page limit in REST API

Tags: rest-api

WP 4.8.2

We need to increase the per_page limit on responses to a REST API request.
afaik – the limit is 100

There used to be a way to filter that parameter, but it seems this filter hook is no longer working: `rest_post_collection_params`

Is there any way to increase that limit without hacking the code?

We understand the repercussions of increasing the limit, but we need to exceed the per_page in a *single* call for use in code that will not be distributed.

Comment: how can I download this postman collection `rest_post_collection_params`

Comment: It is part of the rest api in WP - there is no need to download anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The collection params accessed via that filter appear to describe the available query params but are not actually used in the query.

I think what you actually want is the [`rest_{$this->post_type}_query` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) which allows you to modify the args before they are passed to `WP_Query::query()`.

Also keep in mind that on the API request the `per_page` arg might be set, but internally that is translated to `posts_per_page` for the actual query args.

Edit: I think I misread the original question...

The [`rest_{$this->post_type}_collection_params`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_collection_params/) does indeed describe the available params.

You should be able to set the `per_page` max at `$params['per_page']['maximum']`.

Comment: I forgot to set the hook to the cpt name -  argh.  Thx for  answer and the link.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, it worked with the following:

```
function maximum_api_filter($query_params) {
    $query_params['per_page']["maximum"]=200;
    return $query_params;
}
add_filter('rest_page_collection_params', 'maximum_api_filter');
```