# fetch more than 100 records in block editor API call

Tags: block-editor, rest-api

This question is related to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242196/wp-api-to-fetch-all-the-media-posts-records-if-count-is-more-than-100), however, I am searching for a way to do this in block editor.

I have this custom React hook which fetches records from custom post type:

```js
export function usePersonnel() {
        const staffList = useSelect(select => select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'staff', {[ '_fields' ]: 'id,meta', per_page: 100}));
        return useMemo(() => {
            return staffList?.map((el, index) => ({...el.meta, ID: el.id}) )
        }, [staffList]);
}
```

how to change this hook to fetch arbitrary number of records by fetching multiple times in chunks of 100 records? The solution probably involves using apiFetch and reading X-WP-TotalPages header value. However, I am not that good with async programming.

Comment: I wonder why people vote for closing this question?